# AndroidManifest class referenced applicationName was not found

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle, android-manifest

I have a problem with my Flutter application, when I used `./gradlew build` I got this error message:

```
Error: Class referenced in the manifest, com.example.pet_store.${applicationName}, was not found in the project or the libraries [MissingClass]
          android:name="${applicationName}"
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I used both Android Studio and VSCode. Also Invalidate Cache/Restart didn't work for me.
My gradle version is 6.7.1

Running ./gradlew build --debug gives me this error message

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downgraded my gradle to `6.6.1` and added these lines to `/android/app/build.gradle` file:

```
android{
//...
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

Then `flutter clean`, `flutter run`, `./gradlew clean` and finally `./gradlew build`
everything works fine.

Comment: It's not the proper answer