# Class referenced in the manifest, was not found in the project or the libraries

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart

I am having a problem with my manifest file and searched everywhere and could not find a solution. Could someone kindly check my Manifest file and let me know why I get the following error:

> Class referenced in the manifest, com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity, was not found in the project or the libraries

```
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.blabber_tech">


   <application
        android:label="blabber_tech"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            >
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />

       <activity
           android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
           android:screenOrientation="portrait"
           android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
    </application> </manifest>
```

Comment: That is only a small, incomplete section of androidmanifest.xml. You need to provide a complete view, properly formatted for us to help you.

Comment: Have you seen this SO post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64140208/flutter-image-cropper-android-manifest-error-com-yalantis-ucrop-ucropactivity.  I haven't used image cropper but hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, saw it. Unfortunately, it did not help.

Comment: I am experiencing a similar problem with starting a service within the manifest aplication <service
            android:name="biz.myecard.mathisfun"
            android:stopWithTask="true" />